# Solving heat PDE with Robin Boundary Conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation

I'm getting stuck with the diffusion equation

$k∂^2u/∂x^2=∂u/∂t$

with $0 < x < 1$,
$t > 0$ and

$u(0, t) = 0,$

$∂u/∂x(1,t)= −hu(1, t),$

$h > 0,$ 
$t > 0$

$u(x, 0) = 1,$

$0 < x < 1.$

So far I've got my answer into the form 
$u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}C_n e^{-\lambda_n^2t}\sin(\mu_nx)$ (not 100% sure this is correct). But now I am struggling to find a value for $C_n$. I think I need to use Fourier inversion but I'm not overly familiar with using this.

Comment: What are your eigenvalues in your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your series expansion is basically correct, but it should be said that $\mu_n$ come from the equation $-h\tan \mu = \mu$, which expresses the boundary condition at $x=1$. The infinite sequence of solutions of this equation, $\mu_n$, does not admit a close form.

Next, $\lambda_n$ in the exponent should be related to $\mu_n$, by way of the PDE. Plugging each term of the series into the PDE shows $\lambda_n^2 = k\mu_n^2$, so there isn't a need to write $\lambda_n$ at all: 
$$
u(x, t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n e^{-k\mu_n^2t}\sin\mu_n x \tag1
$$
To find $C_n$, we have to expand the initial condition $u(x,0)\equiv 1$ in the orthogonal basis $\sin \mu_n x$. (The orthogonality follows from the general theory of eigenfunctions with certain boundary conditions.) This yields
$$
C_n = \frac{\int_0^1 1\sin \mu_n x\,dx}{\int_0^1 \sin^2 \mu_n x\,dx}
= \frac{\mu_n^{-1}(1-\cos \mu_n)}{\frac12 - \frac1{4\mu_n}\sin2\mu_n}
= 4 \frac{1 -  \cos \mu_n}{2\mu_n - \sin 2\mu_n}
$$
We don't get an explicit formula for $C_n$ since there isn't one for $\mu_n$. Asymptotically, $\mu_n$ is like $\pi n$ and so $C_n = O(1/n)$ as $n\to\infty$.