Tricky boundary condition for separable pde
This is a separable PDE which came up in my exam and I couldn't derive the $X$
solution from deductions on the boundary conditions. The boundary condition $
u(0, t) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0, t)
$ doesn't give the usual form where $C_1$ or $C_2$ may be deduced as zero. Can someone show me how to use the initial condition properly? Any help is greatly appreciated!
\[
u_t = u_{xx}
\]
subject to the boundary conditions
\[
u(0, t) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0, t)
\]
and
\[
u(\pi, t) = 0
\]
for (t > 0), along with the initial condition
\[
u(x, 0) = \sin(\pi x).
\]

This may help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2527652/solving-heat-pde-with-robin-boundary-conditions.
